# Combinatorial Identities involving roots of unity

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs, roots-of-unity

I'm looking for combinatorial identities involving roots of unity/complex numbers and binomial coefficients. In Gould's *Combinatorial Identities*, I have come across $$\sum_{j\geq0} \binom{n}{rj} = \frac{1}{r} \sum_{j=0}^{r-1} (1 + w^j)^n$$ and $$\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{\binom{kr}{r}}=\sum_{k=1}^{r-1}-\omega^k(1-\omega^k)^{r-1}\log\frac{1-\omega^k}{-\omega^k}$$ where $\omega$ is a primitive $r$-th root of unity. I am looking for more identities of this flavor.

Comment: Well, the general idea is known as the roots of unity filter. Essentially, in a series, you can use roots of unity to "filter" out the terms you don't want.

Comment: Right. I came across this in researching the first identity, but couldn't find more combinatorial identities involving the roots of unity filter—do you know of any?

Comment: Not many, but the first one extends to any residue mod r, not just 0, for the bottom of the binomial coefficient. The extension is quite easy if you can prove the weaker version.